# UILabel Disappear From Static UITableViewCell with Dynamic Type

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, accessibility

I have static `UITableView` with Basic style cells, default 44 height. There is a label in each cell with Body text style. This way I'm getting Dynamic Type behaviour for free.

It works except if:

1. Open app
2. Open table view
3. Open Settings ang change text size (bigger of smaller)
4. Open app again, labels vanishing.
5. Go to another view (back) and open troubled table again — text changed and looks good

I managed to fix this with following hack

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(preferredContentSizeChanged)
                                                 name:UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)preferredContentSizeChanged
{
    // adjust the layout of the cells
    // for some reason text from labels are disappear
    self.statusBarCell.textLabel.text = @"Status bar";
    self.itemColorCell.textLabel.text = @"Color";
```

But I have another exactly the same `UITableView` and this is not working. I tried outlets for cells and labels. I tried `reloadData` and `setNeedsLayout` methods.

Here is pictures. Labels are yellow and content view is blue:

[image: Before, cells with content]
[image: After, cells without labels]

Comment: This is still a bug in iOS 12.1

Comment: FWIW, this seems to have been resolved in Xcode 11 / iOS 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and wanted to solve this **without code**. So I changed

- the static cell type from basic to custom,
- added my own label
- added leading, trailing and vertical center constraints,
- set the dynamic type check box on the label to on
- and the font of the label to text styles body.  -

**This works even for table views that have no program code / class**

Comment: This works, but unfortunately, only by setting the class to "custom" and adding constraints, as described.

Answer (score 6):

I recently played with static tables and tried to add dynamic type to it. I got the same results as you - one even can see this vanishing label in Apple's own Contacts.app.

Even after changing my table from static to dynamic and implementing a small custom cell containing a UILabel (configured with font as UIFontTextStyleBody in the XIB) the table still didn't seem to update its contents when changing the preferred text size in system prefrences.

However: I accidentally got some results after doing the following: in the subclass for my custom cell I implemented prepareForReuse and re-initialize the label's font to the correct style:

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {

    self.label.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
}
```

With the hack above my table cells adapt their fonts dynamically to changes in system preferences.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I tried it on my other static table and it didn't help. I still need to recreate labels text on `preferredContentSizeChanged` notification.

Comment: No, my "solution" above doesn't work with static tables, but I think internally the problem is the same: the labels in the cells don't update correctly to the new fonts - probably because there is too much caching going on.

Comment: I see, in my answer I'm doing the same line of code. Only I do it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of `UITableViewController`.

Answer (score 4):

I changed table to a dynamic and implemented `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method to assign table label in code. This is not helped me.

Next I changed table view cell style from **basic** to **custom.** I had to add my own label and set up AutoLayout constraints in Storyboard. This is solved the issue. `preferredContentSizeChanged` notification is no longed necessary.

In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.label.font = [UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleBody];
```

I will file an Apple radar later. Looks like we can't use Dynamic Type with static tables.

Good luck and please implement Dynamic Type in your apps. It's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

If you were connecting the outlet of `textLabel`, `detailTextLabel` by yourself, 
please delete the outlet.
and you will use properties of the UITableViewCell.

```
open class UITableViewCell {
    open var textLabel: UILabel? { get }     
    open var detailTextLabel: UILabel? { get }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding [self.table reloadData]; in your preferredContentSizeChanged method.

Comment: Upvoted by mistake (and can't downvote). Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this is a Storyboard issue with the 'basic' tableViewCell style. When a UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification is received, the attributes for the textLabel that were set in Storyboard are 'forgotten', including the text itself. I solved a similar issue by setting the needed textLabel attributes in code instead (in CellForRowAtIndexPath).

Answer (score 0):

The label is getting dropped out of its parent view.  Try this:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    contentView.addSubview(unitLabel)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to have been resolved in iOS 13, but here's a workaround for previous versions…

Remove the notification sent to the table view on size category change - this will stop the table view auto updating

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(tableView!, name: UIContentSizeCategory.didChangeNotification, object: nil)        
}
```

Then update the table yourself…

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    if previousTraitCollection?.preferredContentSizeCategory != traitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```